# What is the best way to remove listener in utile class in android?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a util class which helps me to get specific data from Firebase database the class like that

```
public class FirebaseUtils {  

    private DatabaseReference root;

    public FirebaseUtils(){
        root = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    public void setUerType(Context context,String userid){    
        DatabaseReference reference = root.child("teachers").child(userid);

        reference.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    PrefsHelper.getInstance(context).setUserType("teacher");
                }else {
                    PrefsHelper.getInstance(context).setUserType("student");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

what is the best way to remove the listener should I creat a method in utile class like that

```
public void removeListener(){
    child.removeEventListener(listener);
}
```

and call it in onDetach method in the activity?

Comment: When you add a listener with `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` it will automatically removed after `onDataChange` has been called once. In the vast majority of the cases you should not have to remove such listeners explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but in your case need to create a member of listener's type and not pass anonymous listener's implementation.

Comment: Yes I know ,this is the current state of my code but when adding removeListener method I will modify it first create an instance of ValueEventListener then initialize it in setUserType  and add the listener then remove listener in removeListener method .

Answer (score 0):

As I see in your code, you are using `addListenerForSingleValueEvent()`, which means that the listener will read the data precisely once. That means that your `onDataChange()` method gets triggered with the current value (from the cache if available, otherwise from Firebase servers), and stop listening immediately after that. In this case there is no need to remove the listener.

The only time `addListenerForSingleValueEvent` needs to be canceled is, if there is no network connection when you attach it and the client doesn't have a local copy of the data, either because there was another active listener or because it has a copy of the data on disk.

So in conclusion, there is no need to create a `removeListener()` method at all.

Comment: Is there everything alright, can I help you with other informations?